# CentOS7 high CPU utilization

Tags: linux, process, centos, cpu, cpu-usage

[ca high cpu utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPadD.png)

Can anyone help me figure out what this 'ca' process is?

Comment: You can try this command to locate the `ca` binary:  `readlink -f /proc/31846/exe`

Comment: you can get the more command details while running top command by typing 'c' key. It's too short to investigate about 'ca' process.

Answer (score 0):

ps axo %cpu,command | sort -nr | head

to find hight cpu resource consuming process